# ASP.NET Core unnecessarily calls default authentication handler when other scheme is provided in policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-6.0

In my ASP.NET Core 6 application, I am using two different authentication schemes and policies for different controllers. The default auth scheme is used by almost all controllers while the second one is only used in one controller.
Here is how I defined my authentication schemes and policies:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(FirstAuthDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddScheme<FirstAuthSchemeOptions, FirstAuthHandler>(
        FirstAuthDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { })
   .AddScheme<SecondAuthSchemeOptions, SecondAuthHandler>(
       SecondAuthDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    AuthorizationPolicy policy2 = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(SecondAuthDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireRole("RoleName")
        .Build();

    options.AddPolicy(SecondAuthDefaults.Policy, policy2);

    AuthorizationPolicy defaultAuthorizationPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(FirstAuthDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();

    options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicy;
});
```

In most controllers, I simply use the `[Authorize]` attribute to use the default auth policy which works just fine. In the controller that should use the second policy, I overwrite the `Policy` attribute like this:

```
[Authorize(Policy = SecondAuthDefaults.Policy)]
```

While this technically works fine, I noticed that `HandleAuthenticateAsync` in my `FirstAuthHandler` is still being executed when an endpoint in the controller that uses the second policy is being called. So far, I was under the impression that only the auth schemes specified for the policy via the `AuthorizationPolicyBuilder` are being used, but this does not seem to be the case.

Do I still have to manually overwrite the authentication scheme in the controller by overwriting the `AuthenticationSchemes` in the `Authorize` attribute, or why is the default auth scheme still being used despite the fact that another auth scheme is specified in the used policy?

Comment: I believe you have to map the endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0#apply-policies-to-endpoints

Comment: You could check the source codes here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationMiddleware.cs

Answer (score 1):

You could check the codes in [Authentication MiddleWare](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationMiddleware.cs#L59C9-L74C1):

```
var defaultAuthenticate = await Schemes.GetDefaultAuthenticateSchemeAsync();
        if (defaultAuthenticate != null)
        {
            var result = await context.AuthenticateAsync(defaultAuthenticate.Name);
            if (result?.Principal != null)
            {
                context.User = result.Principal;
            }
            if (result?.Succeeded ?? false)
            {
                var authFeatures = new AuthenticationFeatures(result);
                context.Features.Set<IHttpAuthenticationFeature>(authFeatures);
                context.Features.Set<IAuthenticateResultFeature>(authFeatures);
            }
        }
```

If your default scheme exists,it would Authenticate with default scheme within the scope of Authentication Middleware

And the codes in [AuthorizationMiddleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/AuthorizationMiddleware.cs#L105)

```
var authorizeData = endpoint?.Metadata.GetOrderedMetadata<IAuthorizeData>() ?? Array.Empty<IAuthorizeData>();

var policies = endpoint?.Metadata.GetOrderedMetadata<AuthorizationPolicy>() ?? Array.Empty<AuthorizationPolicy>();

 policy = await AuthorizationPolicy.CombineAsync(_policyProvider, authorizeData, policies);
```

......

```
var policyEvaluator = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IPolicyEvaluator>();

var authenticateResult = await policyEvaluator.AuthenticateAsync(policy, context);
```

I tried with the settings:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("schema1")
    .AddScheme<Schema1Options, Schema1>("schema1", null)
    .AddScheme<Schema2Options, Schema2>("schema2", null);
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    AuthorizationPolicy policy2 = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("schema2")
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireRole("RoleName")       
        .Build();

    options.AddPolicy("Policy2", policy2);

    AuthorizationPolicy defaultAuthorizationPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("schema1")
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();

    options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicy;
});
```

With the Attribute `[Authorize(Policy ="Policy2")]` on the action

Then,Let's debug and pay attention to CallStack:

[image]

Notice in which scope  `HandleAuthenticateAsync` was called

> Do I still have to manually overwrite the authentication scheme in the
> controller by overwriting the AuthenticationSchemes in the Authorize
> attribute

Even if it could work in your senaro,I still suggest you specific the scheme,for one policy could be applied to mutipule scheme like:

```
AuthorizationPolicy policy2 = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("schema2","scheme3")
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireRole("RoleName")       
        .Build();
```

And Athenticate in Authentication middleware is necessary for Role based authorization

Comment: When this [line](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/16f8b03c2f5b4d3bc82a92ddafc642182e39c1b7/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationMiddleware.cs#L62) executes, it ultimately goes [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/16f8b03c2f5b4d3bc82a92ddafc642182e39c1b7/src/Http/Authentication.Abstractions/src/AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.cs#L217) to get the `AuthenticationService`. Where is this service registered? Can you please show me where it's registered in [this](https://github.com/affableashish/blazor-identity-api/blob/main/BlazorServerClient/Program.cs) app?

Comment: I figured this out and documented it [here](https://github.com/affableashish/blazor-identity-api/blob/main/README.md#defaultauthentication).